# query a jsonb array in a select of another query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a user table with a column favorites that is a jsonb

```
favorites:
 [
        {
            "id_doc:": 9,
            "type": "post"
        },
        {
            "id_doc": 10,
            "type": "post"
        }
 ]
```

And I have another table posts where I want to make a query by id and this id must be in the fields id_doc in the favorites user

```
select * from posts where id in (select favorites -> id_doc from users )
```

This is the schema

```
CREATE TABLE dev.users
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    firstname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    lastname character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    password character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    favorites jsonb[],
    CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT email_key UNIQUE (email)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE dev.users
    OWNER to postgres;


CREATE TABLE dev.posts
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('dev.posts_id_seq'::regclass),
    title character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    userid integer NOT NULL,
    description character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT posts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE dev.posts
    OWNER to postgres;
```

How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other ways to accomplish this, but I prefer using CTEs for clarity.  Please let me know in the comments if you have questions about what this does.

```
with elements as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(favorites) as favitem
    from users
), fav_ids as (
  select distinct (favitem->>'id_doc')::int as id_doc
    from elements
)
select p.*
  from posts p
  join fav_ids f on f.id_doc = p.id
;
```

**Update**
Since the column is defined as `jsonb[]` rather than `json`, we need to `unnest()` instead of `jsonb_array_elements()`:

```
with elements as (
  select unnest(favorites) as favitem
    from users
), fav_ids as (
  select distinct (favitem->>'id_doc')::int as id_doc
    from elements
)
select p.*
  from posts p
  join fav_ids f on f.id_doc = p.id
;
```

Comment: I have an error. jsonb_array_elements(jsonb[]) does not exist

Comment: @simo9900 Please update your question to show the table schema. We have to treat `jsonb[]` columns differently than `jsonb`.  I will update my answer.